# Can fixed effects models be validated with out-of-sample data?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I have a 2-way unit and time fixed effects model:

$$y_{it} = a_i + b_t +X_{it}\beta + \epsilon$$

I collect data on a set of units $A$ and $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. The data was collected during the same time. I would like to measure how well the model fit on $A$ predicts the within variation in $B$. Is it possible to do that?

My thinking is that between unit variation will be different between $A$ and $B$, since the units are different, but the within predictions made by the fit on $A$ should be informative of within variation in $B$.

Comment: What is $t$ index referring to

Comment: It refers to time.

Comment: *"My thinking is that between unit variation will be different between A and B, since the units are different, but the within predictions made by the fit on A should be informative of within variation in B."* How are we supposed to answer the question about the relationships between A and B when we have no idea what these sets of units mean and how they relate to each other? (and I also wonder what the word/term 'unit' is supposed to mean)

Comment: *"I would like to measure how well the model fit on A predicts the within variation in B..."* You can **1** make predictions, **2** compute the observed variation **3** compute the difference between prediction and observation **4** use whatever statistic you like to  express the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure how the nature of units matters. I've always seen fixed effects models being described with a generic meaning of unit. In this case you can consider a unit to be a person.